# Heisenberg’s Formulation of Quantum Mechanics and Particle Trajectories

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-interpretations

In the [article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), under the history section, Heisenberg recounts a discussion with Einstein regarding Heisenberg’s matrix mechanics: “ He pointed out to me that in my mathematical description the notion of ‘electron path’ did not occur at all, but that in a cloud-chamber the track of the electron can of course be observed directly.  It seemed to him absurd to claim that there was indeed an electron path in the cloud-chamber, but none in the interior of the atom.” my question is, what is the solution of the question posed by Einstein?

Comment: Related: [Can the Schrodinger equation describe planetary motion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/412053) and also [Why can interaction with a macroscopic apparatus, such as a Stern-Gerlach machine, sometimes not cause a measurement?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/282410) and also [Why aren't particles constantly "measured" by the whole universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460855)  The keyword is "decoherence." We even have a [tag for it](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/decoherence?tab=Votes).

Comment: This is the [Mott problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mott_problem)